# declarative authorization has_(not)_permission_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

I have a (relatively) large rails app which uses declarative authorization for role based permissions. Admin users currently have the following permissions:

```
role :administrator do
  has_omnipotence
end
```

I need to add a higher role (root) which can exclusively have permissions on certain actions.

The obvious thing to do is to get rid of **has_omnipotence** from the administrator role block and manually add all permissions on all controllers but **root_accounts**, but this is painful.  Is there a way that I could do something like the following?

```
role :root do
  has_permission_on [:root_accounts], :to => [:new, :create ... ]
end

role :administrator do
  has_omnipotence {except [:root_accounts], :to => [:new, :create ...]}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such syntax. But you can check for a specific role in your view/controller:

```
<% unless has_role?(:administrator) %>
  <%= link_to 'New root account', new_root_account_path %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
def create
  permission_denied if has_role?(:administrator)
  ...
end
```

It's not very scalable tho.